# I need the best film production video editor

Tags: youtube, video-editor

I recently installed my ubuntu and am new to it.
I have some projects with me related to video editing and since you can see, I have switched from windows to linux. I wanna know the best video editor for Ubuntu/Linux

thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: OpenShot is pretty good. Some people say Kdenlive is better, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: This question is pretty opinionated, so I'm going to flag it as such. If you want a recommendation, I suggest asking on [softwarerecs.se]. Remember to include that you have Ubuntu.

Comment: Alright thanks, I am downloading openshot to find out if it can serve the purpose or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two suggestions:

- OpenShot: a light, easy, full-featured video editor for Linux. You can use it to make some simpler projects.

Pros: extremely easy to use, intuitive, user-friendly, stable.

Cons: lacks a few advanced options for professional edition, such as audio waves. Its keyframe system is pretty poor.

Installation: in a terminal, run `sudo apt-get install openshot frei0r-plugins`.

- KDEnLive: an advanced video editor for Linux. It has an interface very similar to Openshot and is very good at professional video edition.

Pros: very modular (you can install plug-ins, edit your entire interface, etc.), stable, user-friendly, gets frequent updates (unlike Openshot), excellent for simple AND advanced tasks.

Cons: it's not as easy as Openshot, rendering times are long even with low settings (unlike Openshot), requires better hardware (crashes frequently if you have low RAM).

Installation: in a terminal, run `sudo apt-get install kdenlive kde-runtime frei0r-plugins`.

I personally use Kdenlive because it suits all my needs, but used Openshot for a long time. If you need video compositing, you can also take a look at Natron and Lightworks.

Comment: I need a video editor for professional use.

Comment: Then Kdenlive is the best. You may take some time to adapt to the interface, but when you do, it's awesome.

Comment: I need it for some advertisement and youtube related videos, I hope it proves to be worth it.

Comment: Believe me, it is. Kdenlive can easily replace Sony Vegas. It's just like Photoshop and GIMP, they can get replaced by each other, it's just a matter of getting used.

Comment: so no openshot I suppose. My friends were recommended me to use openshot :/

Comment: No, sorry. Way too simple. But Openshot 2.0 is to be released in February. It's supposed to bring awesome new features. You may give it a try when it's released.

Comment: Yeah, that's what am doing right now. I have started testing openshot right now, later am gonna checkout kdenlive too.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using Kdenlive for a couple of years now and really like it! I only ever had one issue with it. And it's great because you can proxy the clips which help a lot while editing on an older machine. These are examples https://www.youtube.com/user/garykennedy message through there if you need any help.